# Cannot Access leaflet mapObject in vue3

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet, vuejs3

```
 <LMap v-bind="mapOptions" ref="mapRef">
        LTileLayer v-bind="tileLayerOptions" />
 </LMap>
```

`I can Access it fine in vue 2 like console.log(this.$refs.map.mapObject)`

but its undefined in vue3

```
 const mapRef = ref(null)

  //mounted
 console.log(mapRef.value.mapObject)

 return {
   mapRef,
 }
```

I already try everything I can but no luck

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of documentation for vue-leaflet for Vue 3, so hopefully you're comfortable with exploring source code or console logging objects.  If you do console log just `mapRef.value` you'll see the available properties and methods, of which, `mapObject` is not one.  Looks like it's been replaced with `leafletObject`.

The earliest you can use the leafletObject is after the map's `ready` event is fired, so you should be able to console.log the object following that event:

```html
<LMap v-bind="mapOptions" ref="mapRef" @ready="isReady">
  <LTileLayer v-bind="tileLayerOptions" />
</LMap>
```

```js
const mapRef = ref()

function isReady() {
  if (mapRef.value) {
    console.log(mapRef.value.leafletObject)
  }
}

// usage of normal leaflet functions can be called with the leafletObject
function zoomOut() {
  mapRef.value.leafletObject.zoomOut(1)
}
function zoomIn() {
  mapRef.value.leafletObject.zoomIn(1)
}
</script>
```